# Compare changes with latest from repo

Tags: eclipse, svn, repository

Eclipse shows me with the symbol `>` which files I have modified, after the last repository update.  Before commiting, I want to see the changes I made.
When I go `right click->Team->Synchronize with repository` I get exactly what I want. The problem is, I only get the view for this one file I clicked. I need to change the view back to Java, to be able to chose the next modified file.

Is it possible, to compare all modified files, one by one, with the latest edition from the repository, without changing the view after each file?

Comment: right click the project and do the same operation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of right clicking a specific file, you can right click the entire project and perform the same operation you describe.